# How to hide existing post comments in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

So far I know that I need to use the following filter hook to remove the existing post comments;

```
add_filter('comments_array', 'fn_comments_array', 10, 2);
function fn_comments_array ( $data ) {
    return $data = [];
}
```

But its doesn't remove/hide the existing post comments. Do you know why?

To show the comments I am using following code in comments.php file:

```
wp_list_comments( array(    
    'style'         =>  '<div>',
    'per_page'      =>  10,
    'avatar_size'   =>  50,
    'callback'      =>  'mytheme_comment',
    'type'          =>  'comment',
    'avatar_size'   =>  100,
));
```

Comment: can you try to add  in your function, above return 
global $wp_query, $wpdb;

Comment: did you but no change.

Comment: strange things. If I print_r($data) then I can see all comments after that I can see the formated comments list too.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you check?

Comment: Do you want to hide/deactivate ALL comments?

Comment: Yes, I want hide/deactivate all comments

Comment: There's an article here describing that: https://themeisle.com/blog/disable-comments-in-wordpress/